# Include file according to option selected in dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, select

I am working on a wordpress cms. I need to include a php file according to the option selected in a drop down. I have been dealing with including single file like this. How can I do it with dropdown ?

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="submit" name="example_name">
</form>

<?php if(isset($_POST['example_name'])) :
   get_template_part( 'stuffs/some_important_template');
   endif;
?>
```

I have this example form. But I have no clue beyond this. Please help.

```
<form id="selection_form" action="" method="post">
    <select name="select-mode" id="select-mode">
        <option value ="">FIRST FILE</option>
        <option value ="">SECOND FILE</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="select_mode_submit" value="GET FILE">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold a list of templates in an array, and select one based on the posted value

```
<?php 

$includes=array(
         'temp1'=>'stuffs/some_important_template',
         'temp2'=>'stuffs/another_important_template'
         );

if(isset($_POST['select-mode']) && array_key_exists($_POST['select-mode'], $includes)) :
    get_template_part($includes[$_POST['select-mode']]);
endif;
?>

<form id="selection_form" action="" method="post">
    <select name="select-mode" id="select-mode">
    <option value ="temp1">FIRST FILE</option>
    <option value ="temp2">SECOND FILE</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="select_mode_submit" value="GET FILE">
</form>
```