# Include php file by selected option value

Tags: javascript, html

Would like to ask you how I can change include link by selected value.

Select form:

```
<select>
    <option value="folder1">1</option>
    <option value="folder2">2</option>
    <option value="folder3">3</option>
</select>
```

If i selected 3 value include link should be like this:

```
<?php include '/folder3/firstpage.php' ?>
<?php include '/folder3/secondpage.php' ?>
<?php include '/folder3/thirdpage.php' ?>
```

Link to  [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ewz5Lghu/1/)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913240/include-php-file-based-on-dropdown-selection/40913642 **and** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981051/include-file-according-to-option-selected-in-dropdown

Comment: Hello @s.kuznetsov, I can not cleared out. Could you can help me more with that? 
I really appreciate that for your answer.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I want to get velue from select form to my include file.
If I choose 3 option I got in all my includes folder3. I added JSFiddle how it should look.

Comment: you want to show your `.php` file content? it need ajax ajax or iframe

Comment: Hello @uingtea yes, I want show my .php file content but wihtout iframe.

Answer (score 1):

below is to show the `.php` file content using jQuery Ajax

note: in client side (browser) you can't get/include `.php` file without iframe or XHR (ajax)

```js
function getContent(selector, url) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      $(selector).text(data.responseText)
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err)
      alert(err.statusText)
    }
  })
}

$("#test").on("change", function() {
  var firstpage = '/' + $("#test").val() + '/firstpage.php';
  var secondpage = '/' + $("#test").val() + '/secondpage.php';
  var thirdpage = '/' + $("#test").val() + '/thirdpage.php';
  getContent("#debug", firstpage);
  getContent("#debug1", secondpage);
  getContent("#debug2", thirdpage);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="test">
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="folder1">Folder1</option>
  <option value="folder2">Folder2</option>
  <option value="folder3">Folder3</option>
</select>
<br><br> 

firstpage: <span id="debug"></span><br> 
secondpage: <span id="debug1"></span><br> 
thirdpage: <span id="debug2"></span><br>
```